# python `with .. as ..` statement and multiple return values

Tags: python, sockets, with-statement, contextmanager

I am trying to use a python with-statement (a.k.a. a context manager) to ensure that the TCP connection socket created by `server_socket.accept()` is always closed. However the obvious form does not work because `accept()` returns multiple values.

Is there a way use a with-statement for functions with multiple return values?

A minimal example is below, I want to use something like the commented code to replace the try/finally block.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket
from socket import socket as Socket

with Socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as server_socket:

        server_socket.bind(('', 8011))
        server_socket.listen(1)
        print("server ready")

        while True:

            # with server_socket.accept() as (connection_socket, _):
            #     request = connection_socket.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
            #     reply = request.upper()
            #     connection_socket.send(reply.encode('ascii'))

            try:
                connection_socket, _ = server_socket.accept()
                request = connection_socket.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
                reply = request.upper()
                connection_socket.send(reply.encode('ascii'))

            finally:
                connection_socket.close()
```

The error message when using the commented with-statement is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 26, in <module>
    with server_socket.accept() as (connection_socket, _):
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Presumably this is because a tuple does not have the `__exit__` attribute required for `with`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The return value of `socket.socket` has a built-in context manager that implements `__exit__` and `__enter__`.  The tuple returned by `accept` does not, but you can break out the client socket and address from the tuple and use `with` on the client socket alone:

```
import socket

with socket.socket() as s:
    s.bind(('',8000))
    s.listen(1)
    c,a = s.accept(s)
    with c:
        while True:
            data = c.recv(1024)
            if not data: break
            c.sendall(data)
```